# Insertar item en una tabla de otra con condiciones e incluyendo la no duplicación en MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

quiero importar productos a través de unos procedimientos de MYSQL, Sencillamente tengo la tabla "importar_items" donde se encuentran los ítems a importar, y tengo la tabla productos, y precios que seria a donde serian destinados los datos:
Los datos son ingresador de manera manual hasta esta tabla "Importar_items" y un procedimiento compruebobara si los productos están duplicados.
A continuación las declaraciones de dichas tablas descritas:
**Tabla importar_items**

```
CREATE TABLE `importar_items` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `idimportar` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `cantidad` DECIMAL(11,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `nombre` VARCHAR(250) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `categoria` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `codigobarras` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `precio` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `idimportar` (`idimportar`) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

**Tabla Productos**

```
CREATE TABLE `productos` (
    `cantidad` DECIMAL(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    `cantidadbultoabierto` DECIMAL(11,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `cantidadbultocerrado` DECIMAL(11,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `categoria` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `eliminado` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `especial` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `fecha` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `ingresosbrutos` DECIMAL(3,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    `nombre` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
    `proveedor` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `stockminimo` DECIMAL(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '4.00',
    `tipodeproducto` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `ultimamodificacion` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
    `balanzaid` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
    UNIQUE INDEX `id` (`id`, `nombre`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `eliminado` (`eliminado`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `ultimamodificacion` (`ultimamodificacion`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `id2` (`id`) USING BTREE,
    FULLTEXT INDEX `nombre` (`nombre`),
    FULLTEXT INDEX `nombre_2` (`nombre`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

**Tabla Precios**

```
CREATE TABLE `precios` (
    `ganancia` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `idproducto` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `impuesto` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    `ingresosbrutos` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    `numerodepreciodelista` INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `porcentaje` DECIMAL(4,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    `precio` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    `precio2` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    `costo` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
    UNIQUE INDEX `id` (`id`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `numerodepreciodelista` (`idproducto`) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Las tablas de destino son "productos" y "Precios": La idea de las tablas es la siguiente, cada producto está detallado en la tabla productos y se identifica con productos.id y productos.nombre, cada producto le corresponde un precio, del cual se relaciona de la siguiente manera productos.id = precios.idproducto. Cada producto puede tener varios precios diferidos por Precio.numerodepreciodelista.
Es decir el producto "PAN" tiene un precio de "3" como número de precio de lista 0, y este no se puede repetir, no puede tener dos precios Precio.numerodepreciodelista=0.

El procedimiento verifica si existe el producto y su  precio y lo inserta, y sino lo actualiza
y acá está el problema. Los productos los agrega y si están agregados actualiza su nombre. Pero los precios los inserta aunque ya exista, y no como correspondería que es actualizar el "Precio.precio"

¡Cada importación se identifica con un id_importacion para agrupar los productos por proceso, para diferenciar de otra por si existe el caso de que se estén haciendo dos importaciones a la vez!

A continuación la formula:

```
/*aquí agrego los productos */
INSERT IGNORE INTO productos (nombre, cantidad, fecha) SELECT nombre, cantidad, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() FROM importar_items WHERE importar_items.idimportar= ultimoidimportar;
/*aquí actualizo los nombre de los productos por sus codigo de barras*/
update productos a inner JOIN codigobarras b ON (a.id = b.idproducto ) INNER JOIN importar_items c ON c.codigobarras = b.codigobarras set a.nombre = c.nombre  where c.idimportar= ultimoidimportar AND c.codigobarras IS NOT NULL;
```

La consulta de la cuestión es la siguiente:

```
/*aqui los precios que debo ingresar pero se duplican*/
INSERT IGNORE INTO precios (idproducto, precio) SELECT productos.id, importar_items.precio FROM importar_items , productos WHERE productos.nombre = importar_items.nombre AND importar_items.idimportar= ultimoidimportar AND importar_items.precio IS NOT null;
```

Mi idea sería un INSERT INTO precios de idproducto y precio de IMPORTAR_ITEMS sin que esten repetidos y la condición de precios.numerodepreciodelista=0 no esté repetida. en ese caso actualizar!

En el caso de que si existen si me funciona con la siguiente consulta:

```
/*actualizo precios*/
update precios u inner JOIN productos c ON (u.idproducto = c.id ) INNER JOIN  importar_items d ON d.nombre = c.nombre set u.precio = d.precio  where u.numerodepreciodelista = 0 AND d.idimportar= ultimoidimportar AND d.precio IS NOT NULL;
```

Estoy ingresando todas las funcinoes que si funcionan para que puedan ver de que manera se realiza la importacion.

¿Se puede importar los productos y precios sin duplicarlos y en el caso de que se encuentren actualizar producto.nombre y precio.precio? Y para hacer que el procedimiento sea más rápido, se puede hacer todo en un solo query? para evitar el exceso de tiempo de consulta al realizar una importación de miles de productos? bueno espero que alguien pueda ayudarme Desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: En ese caso, no sería mejor un `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`??

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: El usuario tiene la opcion de actualizar o no los productos, si existiera la necesidad si, pero como puedo hacer que no se repita numerodepreciodelista=0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Mi idea sería un INSERT INTO precios de idproducto y precio de
> IMPORTAR_ITEMS sin que esten repetidos y la condición de
> precios.numerodepreciodelista=0 no esté repetida. en ese caso
> actualizar!

Para ello existe `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

```
INSERT INTO t1 (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;
```

---

Ejemplo:

```
INSERT INTO ejemplo (id_ejemplo,descripcion) 
  VALUES (34,'qwerty') 
  ON DUPLICATE KEY 
    UPDATE descripcion = 'qwerty';

SELECT descripcion FROM ejemplo WHERE id_ejemplo = 34;
-- Esto devuelve: qwerty

INSERT INTO ejemplo (id_ejemplo,descripcion) 
  VALUES (34,'asdf') 
  ON DUPLICATE KEY 
    UPDATE descripcion = 'asdf';

SELECT descripcion FROM ejemplo WHERE id_ejemplo = 34;
-- Esto ahora devuelve: asdf
```

Comment: ¿pero existe la condición extra de que no puede haber precios.numerodepreciodelista=0, como lo puedo formular? es una condición del mismo destino... me explico?, el destino a realiar la actualizacion no debe tener IDPRODUCTO repetido y numerodepreciodelista=0 Entonces si UPDATE

Comment: Puedes añadir multiples condiciones dentro del UPDATE - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43001991/mysql-insert-on-duplicate-update-multiple-conditions

Comment: Para quien le de flojera leer la publicación: se puede usar una subquery y condicionales como `CASE` en la sentencia `UPDATE` de `ON DUPLICATE`